# removing trailing slashes from proxy pass statements in NginX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Trying to redirect /url to a SPA backend hosted elsewhere which accepts parameters inline, this generates some issues because the proxy pass is passing the trailing slash and breaking the linking IE:

`http://hostname/target?variable=1&page=1` gets converted to `http://hostname/target/?variable=1&page=1`

Ngnix config block looks like this:

```
    location ^~ /target/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass $remote_host/target/;
    }
```

I've already tried:

- removing trailing slashes (redirect loop)
- Adding `proxy_redirect $remote_host/target/$ $remote_host/target/$1;`
- rewriting `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`

All to no avail for now.

Comment: The config block in your question only matches URIs with a trailing `/`. You need to remove the trailing `/` from the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original answer turned out to be correct, the issue ended up being a bug on the backend application doing weird redirects